# How to make my Discord bot respond to both custom prefixes and mentions when I use a function to get the prefix?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to preface this with saying that I asked this question previously and it got closed, marked as a duplicate. I *saw* those other questions before. I tried those solutions. They didn't work. They don't work with prefix *functions*, only prefix *strings*. This is why I asked the question. I have reworded a few things, added info to the title, as much as I can think of to get this question through so I can get the answer I need. Please, please do not close this one. I want an answer that **works**.

I have a function that retrieves a custom prefix from a database file, but I would like to implement the ability to also respond to mentions, as in the `when_mentioned()` function. However, I can not pass in both functions to the `command_prefix` parameter when I am initializing my bot, nor can I add my prefix function to the `when_mentioned_or()` function to combine the two. Is there any way I could go about doing this? I've been searching for answers for the last hour and have found nothing that works yet.

Comment: maybe make a handler using the 
`@bot.event` where the bot recognizes its own tag as text and then can run a function to try and use that as a prefix

Comment: try it yourself and if you really would like me to look into it i can on my free time

Comment: I'll try rigging that up when I get back home, thanks.

Comment: try and compare if the prefix is being used or if the tag is being used and then set the prefix from there

Comment: @ironkey the accepted answer had a more streamlined solution so I went with that one. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: all good they had more time and experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `when_mentioned` function in your own function that retrieves a custom prefix. You can call it with the same `bot` and `msg` that you're passed and it will [return a list of the mention formats (for with and without a nickname) that you can use](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/215fed831c0093569640ea24ff21594938908ecc/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L45-L50). You can then return that list with your custom prefix appended.

Alternatively, you can simply directly return a list with your custom prefix, `bot.user.mention` (see the documentation for [`Bot.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.user) and [`ClientUser.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.mention)), and the nickname format for that mention (`<@!{user_ID}>` rather than `<@{user_ID}>`; see the documentation for [`ClientUser.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.id)).

Comment: I'm... not sure how that didn't occur to me. Thanks. I'll be sure to try that once I get back home.